# PHP Iterating simplexml in foreach loop

Tags: php, xml, loops, foreach, simplexml

I have a simplexml object which looks as below

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<SalesInvoices xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://api.unleashedsoftware.com/version/1">
    <SalesInvoice>
        <OrderNumber>100</OrderNumber>
    </SalesInvoice>
    <SalesInvoice>
        <OrderNumber>101</OrderNumber>
    </SalesInvoice>
</SalesInvoices>
```

I want to iterate through it and print only the order number.  I use this script:

```
foreach ($xml->SalesInvoices->SalesInvoice as $salesinvoice) {
    echo "hello";
    echo $salesinvoice->OrderNumber;
}
```

When I do this I get no output from the loop at all, even the "hello" does not print.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do

```
<?php

$string = '<?xml version="1.0"?>
<SalesInvoices xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://api.unleashedsoftware.com/version/1">
    <SalesInvoice>
        <OrderNumber>100</OrderNumber>
    </SalesInvoice>
    <SalesInvoice>
        <OrderNumber>101</OrderNumber>
    </SalesInvoice>
</SalesInvoices>';
$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);

foreach($xml as $SalesInvoice) {
    print $SalesInvoice->OrderNumber;
}
```

Comment: I've edited the response. SalesInvoices (plural) is the root element so it does not need to be pathed out. Since all that it contains is the SaleInvoice elements you can just `foreach($xml` directly

Comment: `foreach( $xml->SalesInvoice ...` (singular) would also have worked. The important thing to remember is that `$xml` represents the root node, not an abstract Document object.